# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.data.util.CloseableIterator

Tags: mongodb, spring-data

While deploying Spring based web application, I am getting this exception and not able to find any jar which has the class CloseableIterator. Kindly suggest/guide!

Here is the stack trace of the server while deploying the app

```
    HTTP Status 500 - Servlet.init() for servlet rest threw exception

type Exception report

message Servlet.init() for servlet rest threw exception

description The server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

exception

javax.servlet.ServletException: Servlet.init() for servlet rest threw exception
    org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:610)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:98)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:950)
    org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1040)
    org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:607)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1721)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1679)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

root cause

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'usersRepository': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate com.miet.kmpro.dao.UsersRepository.mongoTemplate; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/data/util/CloseableIterator
    org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:334)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1214)
    .................
root cause

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate com.miet.kmpro.dao.UsersRepository.mongoTemplate; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/data/util/CloseableIterator
    org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:573)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:88)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:331)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1214)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:543)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:772)
    org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:839)
    org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:538)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:668)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:634)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:682)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:553)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:494)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:136)
    javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:158)
    org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:610)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:98)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:950)
    org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1040)
    org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:607)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1721)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1679)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

root cause

java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/data/util/CloseableIterator
    java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
    java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2701)
    java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods(Class.java:1975)
    org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.getDeclaredMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:609)
    org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.doWithMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:521)
    org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.doWithMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:507)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.determineCandidateConstructors(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:241)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.determineConstructorsFromBeanPostProcessors(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1069)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1042)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:510)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.findAutowireCandidates(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1192)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1116)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1014)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:545)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:88)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:331)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1214)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:543)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:772)
    org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:839)
    org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:538)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:668)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:634)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:682)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:553)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:494)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:136)
    javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:158)
    org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:610)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:98)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:950)
    org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1040)
    org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:607)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1721)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1679)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

root cause

java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.data.util.CloseableIterator
    org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1720)
    org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1571)
    java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
    java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2701)
    java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods(Class.java:1975)
    org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.getDeclaredMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:609)
    org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.doWithMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:521)
    org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.doWithMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:507)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.determineCandidateConstructors(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:241)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.determineConstructorsFromBeanPostProcessors(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1069)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1042)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:510)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.findAutowireCandidates(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1192)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1116)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1014)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:545)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:88)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:331)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1214)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:543)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:772)
    org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:839)
    org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:538)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:668)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:634)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:682)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:553)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:494)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:136)
    javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:158)
    org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:610)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:98)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:950)
    org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1040)
    org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:607)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1721)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1679)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

note The full stack trace of the root cause is available in the Apache Tomcat/7.0.53 logs.
Apache Tomcat/7.0.53
```

Libraries I am using in my project

```
com.springsource.org.aopalliance-1.0.0.jar
commons-logging-1.1.1.jar
jackson-annotations-2.4.1.jar
jackson-core-2.4.1.jar
jackson-databind-2.4.1.jar
jdom-1.1.3.jar
jstl-1.2.jar
mongo-java-driver-2.9.0.jar
org.springframework.data.core_1.3.1.release.jar
org.springframework.transaction_3.0.5.RELEASE.jar
rome-1.0.jar
spring-aop-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar
spring-aspects-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar
spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar
spring-context-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar
spring-context-support-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar
spring-core-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar
spring-data-commons-1.8.0.RELEASE.jar
spring-data-commons-core-1.4.0.RELEASE.jar
spring-data-mongodb-1.8.2.RELEASE.jar
spring-expression-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar
spring-instrument-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar
spring-instrument-tomcat-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar
spring-jdbc-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar
spring-jms-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar
spring-messaging-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar
spring-orm-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar
spring-tx-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar
spring-web-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar
spring-webmvc-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar
```

rest-servlet.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans:beans xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
        xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
        xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
        xsi:schemaLocation="
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans     
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.0.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.0.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-4.0.xsd">

    <context:annotation-config/>
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.miet.kmpro.beans"/>
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.miet.kmpro.dao"/>
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.miet.kmpro.springctrls"/>
    <mvc:annotation-driven />


    <!-- Define the MongoTemplate which handles connectivity with MongoDB -->
    <beans:bean id="mongoTemplate" class="org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate">
        <beans:constructor-arg name="mongo" ref="mongo" />
        <beans:constructor-arg name="databaseName" value="kmpro" />
    </beans:bean>

    <!-- Factory bean that creates the MongoDB instance -->
    <beans:bean id="mongo" class="org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoFactoryBean">
        <beans:property name="host" value="localhost"/>
    </beans:bean>

    <!-- Use this post processor to translate any MongoExceptions thrown in @Repository annotated classes -->
    <beans:bean class="org.springframework.dao.annotation.PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor"/>



    <!-- JSON Support -->
    <!--<bean name="viewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.BeanNameViewResolver"/>-->
    <!--<bean name="jsonTemplate" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.json.MappingJackson2JsonView"/>-->

</beans:beans>
```

UserDetails.java

```
package com.miet.kmpro.beans;

import org.springframework.data.annotation.Id;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.mapping.Document;
//import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.Id;

@Document
public class UserDetails{
    @Id
    private String userID;
    private String userName;
    private String mailID;
    private int roleID;
    private Subscriptions subscriptions;
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;

    public UserDetails(String userID, String userName, String mailID, int roleID, Subscriptions subscriptions, String firstName, String lastName){
        super();
        this.userID=userID;
        this.userName=userName;
        this.mailID=mailID;
        this.roleID=roleID;
        this.subscriptions=subscriptions;
        this.firstName=firstName;
        this.lastName=lastName;
    }

    public String getUserID() {return userID;}
    public String getUserName(){return userName;}
    public String getMailID(){return mailID;}
    public int getUserRole() {return roleID;}
    public Subscriptions getSubscriptions(){return subscriptions;}
    public String getFirstName(){return firstName;}
    public String getLastName(){return lastName;}

    public void setUserID(String userID) {this.userID=userID;}
    public void setUserName(String userName){this.userName=userName;}
    public void setMailId(String mailID){this.mailID=mailID;}
    public void setUserRole(int roleID) {this.roleID=roleID;}
    public void setSubscriptions(Subscriptions subscriptions){this.subscriptions=subscriptions;}
    public void setFirstName(String firstName){this.firstName=firstName;}
    public void setLastName(String lastName){this.lastName=lastName;}

}
```

MultiUserResponse.java

```
package com.miet.kmpro.dao;

import java.util.List;

import com.miet.kmpro.beans.UserDetails;

public class MultipleUserResponse {
  private boolean success;
  private List<UserDetails> users;

  public MultipleUserResponse(boolean success, List<UserDetails> users) {
    this.success = success;
    this.users = users;
  }

  public boolean isSuccess() {
    return success;
  }
  public void setSuccess(boolean success) {
    this.success = success;
  }
  public List<UserDetails> getUsers() {
    return users;
  }
  public void setUsers(List<UserDetails> users) {
    this.users = users;
  }
}
```

UserRepository.java

```
package com.miet.kmpro.dao;

import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.query.Criteria;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.query.Query;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.query.Update;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

import com.miet.kmpro.beans.UserDetails;

@Repository
public class UsersRepository{
    public static final String COLLECTION_NAME = "users";

    @Autowired
    private MongoTemplate mongoTemplate;

    public void addUser(UserDetails userDetails) {
        if (!mongoTemplate.collectionExists(UserDetails.class)) {
            mongoTemplate.createCollection(UserDetails.class);
        }
        mongoTemplate.insert(userDetails, COLLECTION_NAME);
    }

    public UserDetails getUserByUserName(String userName) {
        return mongoTemplate.findOne(
        Query.query(Criteria.where("userName").is(userName)), UserDetails.class, COLLECTION_NAME);
    }

    public List<UserDetails> getAllUsers() {
        return mongoTemplate.findAll(UserDetails.class, COLLECTION_NAME);
    }

    public UserDetails deleteUsers(String userName) {
        UserDetails userDetails = mongoTemplate.findOne(
        Query.query(Criteria.where("userName").is(userName)), UserDetails.class, COLLECTION_NAME);
        mongoTemplate.remove(userDetails, COLLECTION_NAME);

        return userDetails;
    }

    public UserDetails updateIssuer(String userName, UserDetails userDetails) {
        Query query = new Query();
        query.addCriteria(Criteria.where("userName").is(userName));

        Update update = new Update();
        update.set("firstName", userDetails.getFirstName());
        update.set("lastName", userDetails.getLastName());

        mongoTemplate.updateFirst(query, update, UserDetails.class);

        return userDetails;
    }
}
```

UsersCntrl.java

```
package com.miet.kmpro.springrestcntrls;

import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.CrossOrigin;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseBody;


import com.miet.kmpro.beans.UserDetails;
import com.miet.kmpro.beans.Subscriptions;
import com.miet.kmpro.beans.FeedCategory;
import com.miet.kmpro.dao.UsersRepository;
import com.miet.kmpro.dao.MultipleUserResponse;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.ArrayList;

@RestController
public class UsersCntrl {
    @Autowired
    private UsersRepository usersRepository;


    @CrossOrigin(origins = "http://localhost:8787")
    @RequestMapping(value = "/users/{name}", method = RequestMethod.GET, headers="Accept=application/json")
    //public String getUserDetails(@PathVariable String name) {
    @ResponseBody
    public MultipleUserResponse getUserDetails(@PathVariable String name) {
        List<UserDetails> allUsers = usersRepository.getAllUsers();
        MultipleUserResponse multiUsersInfo = new MultipleUserResponse(true, allUsers);

        return multiUsersInfo;
        //return "{\"userName\":\"Rishi\"}";
    }
}
```

web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5">
    <display-name>SpringServiceSample</display-name>
    <welcome-file-list>
```

.......

```
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>rest</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>
            org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
        </servlet-class>


        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>rest</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/service/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
```

.....

Comment: It would be better to show the stacktrace of the exception so one could see the class where the exception is thrown.

Comment: @StefanHegny: Please refer the following:  root cause

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'usersRepository': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate com.miet.kmpro.dao.UsersRepository.mongoTemplate; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/data/util/CloseableIterator

Answer (score 1):

CloseableIterator belongs to the Spring Data Core jar file.

http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.data/spring-data-commons-core

Add this jar to your project if it cannot be found.

Edit:

Sorry posted the wrong link.

Have you tried the following jar file

http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.data/spring-data-commons

Comment: Hi Blairmeister, I have done that already. But this jar doesnot have the mentioned class file. spring-data-commons-core-1.4.0.RELEASE.jar

Comment: @Rishi You need to clean up your classpath. Remove `spring-data-commons-core`, `org.springframework.data.core`, and upgrade the version of `spring-data-commons` to `1.11.1.RELEASE`. You maybe want to get rid of `org.springframework.transaction_3.0.5.RELEASE` as all other Spring Framework artifacts refer to version `4.2.4.RELEASE`.

Comment: @blairmeister point noted. I am on it now...Thanks for looking into it. I will update you in few minutes once done. Thanks again!

Comment: Hi @blairmeister
That exception is resolved but new exception has occurred related to logger jar
nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate com.miet.kmpro.dao.UsersRepository.mongoTemplate; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/slf4j/Logger

Kindly suggest the jar file to solve this problem with version.
Also how did you manager to find the exact version of the commons jar. Thanks in advance for your help :-)

Comment: Hi @blairmeister
This log problem is resolved and now new exception has occurred.
Logger problem Resolution: I included the following jar 
http://central.maven.org/maven2/org/slf4j/slf4j-api/1.7.21/slf4j-api-1.7.21.jar

New exception is as follows:
Bean instantiation via constructor failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/mongodb/MongoClient

Isn't there a defined list of jars :-/ ?

Comment: Hi @blairmeister

I have resolved the MongoClient class problem by replacing jar mongo-java-driver-2.9.0.jar with mongo-java-driver-2.13.0 : http://central.maven.org/maven2/org/mongodb/mongo-java-driver/2.13.0-rc0/mongo-java-driver-2.13.0-rc0.jar

But the new problem is resource mapping
WARNING: No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/SSLSpringRestApp5/service/users/Rishi] in DispatcherServlet with name 'rest'

I am getting 
HTTP: 404 when I am hitting the following URL:
https://localhost:8443/SSLSpringRestApp5/service/users/Rishi

Kindly suggest the configuration changes.

Comment: I am not sure what configuration changes caused this URI problem but it was working earlier! Kindly guide and thanks for your help so far!!

Comment: Anyone who faced similar problem, kindly help. I tried to explore other URI patterns and but that did not resolve the problem. I am not sure whether there is any problem with my configurations. Kindly help on urgent basis!!

Comment: Problem resolved....
Following changes were done
Commented line:
    <context:annotation-config/>
Replaced following three lines
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.miet.kmpro.beans"/>
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.miet.kmpro.dao"/>
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.miet.kmpro.springctrls"/>

with <context:component-scan base-package="com.miet.kmpro.beans, com.miet.kmpro.dao, com.miet.kmpro.springrestcntrls"/> 

Silly mistake was that I was mentioning wrong package name as com.miet.kmpro.springcntrls instead of com.miet.kmpro.springrestcntrls

Comment: sorry I havent replied sooner. have been quite busy. Glad you have it resolved though! :)

Answer (score 0):

The main resolution was given by @blairmeister

You need to clean up your classpath. Remove spring-data-commons-core, org.springframework.data.core, and upgrade the version of spring-data-commons to 1.11.1.RELEASE. You maybe want to get rid of org.springframework.transaction_3.0.5.RELEASE as all other Spring Framework artifacts refer to version 4.2.4.RELEASE

Remaining problems were not related to CloseableIterator class and the main point to understand over here is that whenever we are using the external jars we need to refer the latest stable release of the jars which has the required class files for which the NoClassDefinitionFoundException is thrown. Thanks a lot Stackoverflow for this nice forum!!